# Can I drop multiple URLs from Google's Cache using a wildcard in a query string?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I made a mistake with one of my sites and a whole bunch of data got picked up by Google before I caught it.  I need to fix this relatively fast by asking Google to drop the cached copy of the pages and then re-spider as they wish.  The URL would be something like:

```
example.com/memberprofile.php?member=XXXXXX
```

Does anyone know if I can submit:

```
example.com/memberprofile.php?member=<some wildcard character>
```

as a single request through webmaster tools?  If not, what are my other alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can delist with a wildcard. Plus a manual delist only lasts for 90 days. You would be better off making a correct robots.txt and letting Google reindex. They should drop your pages that are no longer meant to be crawled, but I don't know how quickly that will occur.

See: https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449&hl=en

You should also add the "noindex" meta tag to your memberprofile.php pages.

See: https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93710

**EDIT:** Did a little more digging...

Instructing Google to drop just the cache, not the entire page, from the index.

See: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734

Proper URLs submitted mention nothing about wildcards, and the section about "Multiple URLs" says to submit each one separately. I don't think wildcards are supported, possibly by design.

See: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=63758

Comment: Thanks jimp.  We DO want the pages indexed, but we inadvertently exposed something in the logged out view and didn't catch it for a day or two and Google did what it was supposed to do.  I'll check the other link now to see if it will do what I need.

Comment: I misunderstood. In that case, it sounds like you don't want the delist feature. I don't think there is a recrawl feature either. Google appears to reindex sites everyday now, so this problem might sort itself out faster than you could do anything manually (assuming no wildcard feature).

Comment: @JCL1178, I did a little more research because I was curious. See my edits above.

Comment: Yeah, I know all about how to delisting or drop the cached copy and when to do what :)  My question is not worded well and I'll fix that.  It appears your research and mine are dovetailing, though...Google does not support a way to mass remove URL's for normal folks.

Answer (score 0):

I read a Google article saying that if you block the robots from reading the pages then Google doesn't crawl them but also does not know that they are no longer there - prolonging the pages from disappearing from your Webmaster Tools report

Comment: would be useful if you could add a link to that article