# How to remove Ever crawled web Pages by Google

Tags: google-search-console, url, googlebot, web-crawlers

I know that we can use noindex, nofollow and robots for excluding the pages from Google Index. This process takes a long long time to clean up website from Google Index. In Webmaster Tools => Index Status => Advanced => Ever crawled, How can I remove the Ever Crawled Pages by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Ever Crawled is just a graph showing the amount of your pages Google has looked at over time. You can't remove it - either in the sense of clearing the graph or somehow using it as an alternative to `noindex` etc.

The only reliable way to remove content from the index, other than completely taking it down, is to use various means of robot control like `noindex`. I'm not sure why you think such measures are unacceptably slow; in my experience that isn't the case.

Comment: [Kindly visit my another post](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/removing-full-site-from-google-index), is there any better way

Comment: @Vineet1982 OK.