# Remove a site from Google search once it has been retired and shut down

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, url-removal

I’m shutting down my website which has a few thousands pages. What is the best way to remove my entire site and related pages from Google search results?

[Removing full site from Google index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/removing-full-site-from-google-index) has been discussed as a possible duplicate but the answers there show what to do with a site that still exists.  Once the site is shut down, those mechanisms such as *robots.txt* won't be available.

Comment: If the site has already "been retired and shut down", does the domain still resolve? That is probably the _quickest_ way to get your site removed from the SERPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is still available and you're still in control of the domain, the quickest way to delist it would be to set up the server to return a status code of `410 - Gone`. That should delist it fairly quickly and you can then turn off the hosting.

Google's crawler will treat the 410 status code as a more deliberate removal status and remove the pages from their index quicker than 404s or unresolved domains.

[Matt Cutts discussed this here](https://youtu.be/xp5Nf8ANfOw?t=71) and more recently [John Mueller also covered it](https://youtu.be/kQIyk-2-wRg?t=1721).

Comment: What if I no longer have control of the domain? (The domain name provider seems to have disappeared without a trace...)